# How can I validate my web.config before I publish according to the publishing profile?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have a few different publishing profiles, for publishing to either our test sites or to our live sites. We also have various 'test' versions of our databases for when we're adding new features. At the moment, I manually modify the web.config before publishing depending on where I'm publishing to. It's never happened, but it's conceivable that I could forget and publish to the live site with a connection string to our 'test' database (this would be very bad).

Is there any way that I can run some sort of routine immediately before publishing that just checks the web.config connection string, and if I'm publishing to live and the connection string is not to the live databases, then it'll refuse to publish?

That would give me a lot of peace of mind, that I've made it impossible for me to do something very stupid.

Comment: Configuration transforms.

Comment: May I ask what you are deploying too? Azure sites for example,  you can set up the connection String in the portal. So you never need to worry about this.

Comment: Not quite an answer to you question, but here is what I do in that situation: I show an alert box when the test database is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup web.config transformations:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

When you configure the transformation files, the web.config will be transformed automatically at publish time based on the Solution Configuration chosen for the deployment.

So, for instance, the production connection string from the Web.Release.config would be placed in the resulting web.config which is eventually deployed.